# Is there a way to automatically generate `Imports` section in the DESCRIPTION file?

Tags: r, r-package

When developing an R package, it is common for me to just turn on Packrat and use a localized repository, and develop as I explore in a session. But when publishing the package, it is a big headache to recall and manually add every dependency I have used in the developed package. Is there a (semi-)automatic way to do this?

For example, in NodeJS development, we can just use `npm install --save` and the dependency will be added automatically to `package.json`.

Comment: I *think* the standard way to do this is to manually insert roxygen(2) `@importFrom` statements in the code ...

Comment: At the very least, it is an extremely _common_ way.

Comment: @joran: better ways? (or are you referring to the fact that (AFAIK) old-school/R-core developers don't tend to use roxygen?)

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, that's all I meant, that some "old-school" R folks might balk at calling roxygen2 the "standard" way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use [`roxygen2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html) to generate your `NAMESPACE` file.

Example way to generate package level documentation:

```
#' @details 
#' \tabular{ll}{
#' Package: \tab \cr
#' Type: \tab Package\cr
#' Version: \tab 1.0.0\cr
#' Date: \tab 2016-05-15\cr
#' License: \tab MIT \cr
#' }
#' @useDynLib pkg
#' @importFrom Rcpp evalCpp
#' @importFrom methods is
#' @importFrom stats ts as.ts is.ts
#' @import ggplot2
"_PACKAGE"
```

**Note:** I tend to keep my import statements together in the package-level documentation. You can use these same statements within function documentation.

Use `@importFrom <pkg> <function1> <function2>` for specific imports.

Otherwise, use `@import <pkg>` for all functions in a given package.

**Edit**

To lock it to a specific version, you will need to modify your `DESCRIPTION` file's `Imports:` section like so:

```
Imports: 
    Rcpp (>= 0.12.5),
    scales (<= 0.4.0),
    grid (== 0.7-4),
    stats
```

Comment: Does it handle specific versions? Do you think it's redundant to use both Roxygen2 and Packrat for dependency handling?

Comment: I prefer import statements with the function documentation because it makes clear *where* in the code you need a given function - if that code goes away later, you know you don't need the dependency any more.

Comment: Note the edit for version specific package loads. @BenBolker I find it easier to centralize everything and prepend the package namespace when calling the package's function e.g. `stats::is.ts()` since I rarely remove dependencies. Again, either approach is valid.

Answer (score 3):

A common way to do this (although not one that's used much by "old school" R programmers, who as far as I know maintain their `NAMESPACE` files by hand ...) is to manually insert roxygen2 `@importFrom` statements in the code ... e.g.

```
# returns a true family() object iff one was given
## to glmmTMB() in the first place ....
##' @importFrom stats family
##' @export
family.glmmTMB <- function(object, ...) {
   object$modelInfo$family
}
```

although it would certainly be helpful to have an automated system, to provide hints if nothing else. Certainly maintaining dependencies in this way (making sure to add `@importFrom` statements as needed for every function that has a dependency) is better than trying to keep track of when dependencies are (still) needed *after* developing the code.

- `@import` and `@importFrom` (which translate to `import` and `importFrom` statements) are both legal, the [R extensions guide](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) says

  > Using importFrom selectively rather than import is good practice and recommended notably when importing from packages with more than a dozen exports.

("good practice" translates to "CRAN maintainers will yell if you don't" ...)

- I don't know if there's a way to do versioned `importFrom` statements: R puts package version dependencies in the `Imports:` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file and `importFrom` statements in the `NAMESPACE` file: roxygen2 generates this information automatically, but I don't think the mapping from roxygen2 directives to `NAMESPACE`/`DESCRIPTION` information is fine-grained enough to support this ...
- Running `R CMD check --as-cran` gives hints about functions from recommended packages that need to be imported.