# R Package: How to automatically generate the `Imports` field in the DESC based on NAMESPACE imports

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I'm developing an R package where I frequently use functions from other packages. I know it's usually best practice to be explicit about other packages in your source code (as in `dplyr::filter()`), but, for example, in plotting functions which are based on `ggplot2` it becomes tedious and verbose to write something like `ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes(x = ...))`, and so on.

Let's say I follow the recommendations and add the `@import ggplot2` tag as a roxygen comment in the respective function. Now, this adds `import(ggplot2)` to the `NAMESPACE` file, which is nice. But, it does *not* add `ggplot2` to the `Imports:` section in the `DESCRIPTION` file, which is exactly what I would like to do. Calling `roxygen2::roxygenize()` does not do this either.

Note that the same question was basically asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263848/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-generate-imports-section-in-the-description-fi), but unless I missed something, the question is not answered (after all, the `Imports:` section is not automatically generated, only the `NAMESPACE` file).

I am aware of the importance of a correctly maintained `NAMESPACE` file, and given there are easy and convenient ways to populate it, I guess my main question is whether there is a function to automatically "translate" the `NAMESPACE` imports into the respective field in the `DESCRIPTION`. I know you can manually edit your `DESCRIPTION` file via `usethis::use_package("ggplot2")` but it seems odd to me to have to specify the same information twice, and in two completely different ways.

Comment: It's not possible as far as I know. However, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738292/how-can-i-automatically-add-update-depends-imports-suggests-versions-in-descript) that may help you.

Comment: I also believe it's not possible.  I suspect the reason is that it is good practice to scope your calls to functions fom other packages in your source code.  That way your intentions explicit and unambiguous.  Relying on indirect scoping (via DESCRIPTION or other means) is not.  So yes, it's (mildly) inconvenient for the package creator, but there are benefits as well: both for the wroiter and the user.